# Load text as JavaScript object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a javascript file for node.js:

```
module.exports = {
     someString: 'blblalb'
}
```

I want to able to read the file as a javascript object, using `fs.readFileSync`. I can't use `require` because I am using a variable that may be modified in runtime to load the file.

Is that possible?

Comment: Possible? Yes it's possible. It's also a *terrible* idea. Either use `require`, or store the data as JSON.

Comment: With `require`, you *can* use runtime variables.

Comment: Well, to be precise, I'm creating a webpack plugin. It seems the `require` is called before the plugin is even instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval('JavaScript string') but is highly recommended not to. It is a serious security risk if you cannot 100% trust the source of the text. If a malicious user figures out a way to modify the text they have complete control of your system. It is not a path I would take or recommend.

```js
const text = 'console.log("Hello")';

eval(text);
```

If I saw that code when I was doing a code review we would definitely be having some words.

Comment: The question already contains the code that needs to be evaluated. If you evaluate `eval('module.exports = ...')`, this will replace current module exports.

Comment: Indeed, you'd have to use a parser or regexes (also notoriously error-prone) to get the code to eval.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to evaluate a file or string variable as child module in hacky yet valid way.

The problem is that Node.js module environment should be unaware of these operations. Child module may load other modules and contain `require(...)`, it will fail if there is no `require` function (there is none if it is evaluated with `vm`) or it uses wrong module relative path (this will happen with `eval`), also there will be no dedicated `module.exports` for a module. This can be fixed by wrapping module source with Node.js [module wrapper](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) that was rewired to match child module location.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Module = require('module');
const path = require('path');

const childModuleAbsPath = path.resolve('./foo/bar.js');
const childModuleBody = fs.readFileSync(childModuleAbsPath);
const childModuleObj = { exports: {} };
const { dir: childModuleDirname, base: childModuleFilename } = path.parse(childModuleAbsPath);
const childRequire = modulePath => module.require(childModuleAbsPath);

require('vm').runInThisContext(Module.wrap(childModuleBody))(
  childModuleObj.exports,
  childRequire,
  childModuleObj,
  childModuleDirname,
  childModuleFilename
);
```

In this case `childModuleObj.exports.someString === 'blblalb'` after `bar` child module was evaluated.

**This is XY problem that should be addressed in another way**.

If the intention is to reevaluate a module with new variables, this can be done by invalidating Node module cache by modifying `require.cache`, e.g. with [`decache`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decache):

```
decache('./foo/bar');
const reloadedBar = require('./foo/bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, drop the variable assignment from the beginning using regex or whatever:

```
let str = ... // <= Here, you drop the "module.exports" 
              //    from the beginning of the string.
              //    So the string is:  '= {someString: 'blblalb'}'
let theNewValue = {};
eval('theNewValue' + str);

console.log(theNewValue); //<= Here is your javascript object.
```

In another words, `eval()` has access to your local variables and you can inject them into the string as simple as that.