# Mock require function in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am trying to mock require using Jest because I am working in a plugin system for electron that will also use `NPM` for resolving dependencies. 
I need to then be able to mock require inside nodejs to be able to test something similar to the next logic.

```js
const load = (installPath, pluginsName, extensionPoint) => {
    require.main.paths.push(`${installPath}/node_modules`)
    pluginsName.forEach(pluginName => {
        let plugin = require(pluginName)
        plugin.onLoad(extensionPoint)
    });
}
module.exports = { load }
```

Is there any simple way of doing this?. As [require is not a global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require), is there is any other way than wrapping and injecting it to test the logic?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52359071/3731501), it's possible to replace `require` in particular module by evaluating it with custom `require`, similarly to how [Node does this internally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52351150/3731501//):

```
const Module = require('module');
const vm = require('vm');

const childModuleAbsPath = path.resolve('./foo/bar.js');
const childModuleBody = fs.readFileSync(childModuleAbsPath);
const childModuleObj = { exports: {} };
const { dir: childModuleDirname, base: childModuleFilename } = path.parse(childModuleAbsPath);
const childRequire = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(...);

vm.runInThisContext(Module.wrap(childModuleBody))(
  childModuleObj.exports,
  childRequire,
  childModuleObj,
  childModuleDirname,
  childModuleFilename
);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will give it a go to validate it works on my context :)